# Why does file synchronization take so long?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

I have a folder with 15 files, each about 100Kb and it more that 2 hours but progress is 0% on all files. Tried to restart, reconnect internet and so on. Why is it?

Comment: What files? What do you want to do with them? What software? That's like asking a rock: "Hey rock, my brain hurt's. Why is it?"

Comment: ubuntu 11.04, ubuntu-one software, any files. Files uploaded from one computer but takes forever to get it on the other. I wrote tags in my question: "11.04"  and  "ubuntu-one", which supposedly be the answers for your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible your account is on one of the servers we've been seeing a very high load on. We have this server in better shape today so, if this was the case, I would expect files to sync much faster for you now.

Comment: Probably it was. Today it took only few sec to do sync. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you still experience that problem try adding the repository from

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntuone/+archive/nightlies

Regarding speed issues I have made good experinces with these updates. But it's not magic, lots of other issues will quite likely remain unsolved.